# Quality Error passing sizeof casted return

Tags: c++, casting, parasoft

I am using a code quality tool called Parasoft C++ Test.  It is complaining about the following:

```
setsockopt(...,sizeof(int));
```

It states:

> In 'setsockopt' function call, do not pass long casted to int expression as '5' function argument

I have tried several different casting options to resolve this, but none of them seem to have any effect.  I can do the following and make it go away:

```
socklen_t socklength = sizeof(int);
setsockopt(...,socklength);
```

Is there a way to call sizeof(int) inline with the setsockopt call without generating this quality error?

Comment: Sometimes such static analyzers rant unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

Cast to a `socklen_t`? something like: `static_cast<socklen_t>(sizeof(int))`, or you can just ignore it...

Comment: hmm, I'm surprised the cast didn't silence it, how about an old style c cast? did you try that too?

Comment: one more thing - maybe `int(sizeof(int))`? I don't have this tool, so can  only guess at what would silence it..

Comment: And that was the second thing I tried.  Still didn't do it.  Glad to see at least someone else out there thinks like me.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the answer is to ignore this warning - it's clearly bogus. Further, the fact that you are having to spend time trying to fix a warning generated against a system header file indicates that something is amiss.

You might try casting the sizeof() to socklen_t, but I expect you already have. The other somewhat obvious thing would be to construct an expression of type int. Perhaps something like:

```
sizeof( int ) & 0xFF.
```

(Of course, on systems where integers are more than 2^255 bits wide, this might fail... :)

Comment: I can make it go away by non-in-lining it.  I tried what you posted but it did not make the error go away.

Comment: That won't help; if `sizeof(int)` has type `long`, then so does `sizeof(int) & 0xFF`.

Comment: Maybe you should suppress this quality error if there is not work around.